# Calculating dianoga's optimized image size?

Tags: media-library, dianoga

Is there a way to programmatically get the Sitecore media files' size which is being optimized by `Dianoga`?

We need to show the image size on the site.

`MediaItem.Size` property is getting us the original image size - which isn't matching the rendered image size which is coming through the `Dianoga` processor.

Any ideas?

Comment: On the live site you are showing the media size?

Comment: Yes, we need to show in a certain design, because we are giving the option to download the image to the user.

Comment: You would not have users downloading the optimised images though, surely?  these are lossy web-optimised versions of the original content.

Comment: Can I turn off optimization by adding something to the url? Since I still want the other images on the site to be optimized?

Comment: Can we stick to one question at the time, please? :-)

Comment: Sure, thank you. I see that i can exclude paths for optimization in the config.

Answer (score 3):

Server-side, no - probably. Dianoga acts as a layer between the Sitecore Media Library and the caching mechanics.

You can get the byte size of the images client-side however. Which would allow you to render these in your page.

This example lists sizes for all images on your page. Adjust as necessary.

```
var imgElems = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for ( var i=0, len = imgElems.length; i < len; i++ ) 
{
    var url = imgElems[i].src || imgElems[i].href;
    if (url && url.length > 0)
    {
        var iTime = performance.getEntriesByName(url)[0];
        console.log(iTime.transferSize); //or encodedBodySize, decodedBodySize
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45409613/81631